# Sort NSDate objects in NSMutableArray using NSSortDescriptor?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nssortdescriptor

In my project, I'm getting some data from an `APi` and I retreive the data into a `NSMutableArray` by parsing the `JSON`. It has a key called "**StartDate**" which is of the format : " `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` "
as shown below

```
StartDate: "5/18/2013 12:00:00 AM"
```

I'm saving these data to a `resultArray` .There are also 4 more keys for an object as my `JSON` is of the form

```
{
    EventId: "xxxx",
    Title: "xxx",
    Location: "xxxx",
    StartDate: "5/18/2013 12:00:00 AM",
    Link: null
}
```

there are multiple such objects here. All that I need to do is to sort the contents of the `resultArray` based on date(either ascending or descending),
I use the following code

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"StartDate" ascending:TRUE];
[resultArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

But I;m getting a shuffled result, the sorting is not correct throughout, can anyone tel me where I had gone wrong .

Thanks

Comment: Maybe (probably) a dupe, but certainly not too localized.  I can only suspect that the down-voters were too lazy to look up the dupes.

Comment: @HotLicks you are right! Thanks for your comment dude, i just posted so to let them be aware not to misuse their rights here! some of them see it as a hobby to downvote and flag!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should work

```c
[resultArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {

    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;

    if (!dateFormatter) {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"; 
    }

    NSString *date1String = [a valueForKey:@"StartDate"];
    NSString *date2String = [b valueForKey:@"StartDate"];

    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date1String];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date2String];

    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

Comment: great answer man, i solved it using your answer, jsut changed dateformat from mm...to MM

Comment: Another option would be to rearrange the strings into yyyymmdd order.  Could be done with a few simple string ops.

Answer (score 3):

Your StartDate seems to be in the string format and I believe its shuffling it for string.. You should convert to NSDate first and than apply this descriptor... Hoping this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't have the permission to change the APi format, so should i replace each date key of my array after converting to the date format?

Comment: You must be storing it in the a data model I guess, where you can specify the property of this model object as NSDate and while feeding it to the object convert it to date... or simpler you can do what you are saying but that is not the standar way to do that... but what the heck... you should try your approach first and if it works later you can convert it to data model objects

Comment: this makes sense, but you could see more simple way by checking the accepted answer.Thanks